# Is using namespaces as well as folders to organize code overkill?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is the use of namespaces as well as folders to organize code overkill?

Example:

```
Folder Structure:
Engine (Root)
--Audio
--Exceptions
--Game
--GFX
--Input
--Math
--Messages
--Physics
--Time
--[global headers]
```

All classes are contained in a `[root]::` namespace to prevent collisions with `std::` and third party code. The Math folder contains a header of some helper (free) functions contained in the `[root]::Math::` namespace and Audio has some more helper (free) functions in the `[root]::AudioHandler::` namespace.

Should I put the classes in each folder into a similarly describing namespace? (i.e. classes in the Physics folder would also be in the `[root]::Physics::` namespace.)

Comment: yes, it is overkilled. you will get tired of writing namespace very fast. Imagine writing `root::Math::vector3f` everytime.

Comment: for the record, visual studio c# does this as part of its standard functionality. Sometimes annoying when i want solution folders but not namespace changes.

Comment: @yngum That's where `using namespace` and namespace aliases come in handy - if used wisely.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious my personal experience is `using namespace` make code harder to read where you have to guess what namespace a function is, not to mention time when function collide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces organise the logical interfaces, directories the "physical" files.

The more code within a single namespace, the more important it is that it's relatively stable and well-coordinated; if identifiers are volatile and uncoordinated you'll likely see conflicts as changes are merged.  Based on your experience of or feel for such conflicts, you can choose your namespaces.

`std::` is an obvious example of a very stable and well coordinated namespace, which means a lot of stuff can be successfully bundled into it.  If you're working on a one-man project - all the way from libraries through application - you're more likely to cope with fewer namespaces too.

On the other hand if you have several global teams working independently - changing/adding identifiers constantly - then it's good to separate the code into namespaces.  Further, if you have regular experiences that the obvious and desirable identifier to use in one system is already in use in another - that suggests namespaces too.